# How do I construct an if statement within a MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, view

Hopefully this question is quick and painless

I have a mvc view where i want to display either one of two values depending on an if statement. This is what I have in the view itself:

```
 <%if (model.CountryId == model.CountryId) %>
        <%= Html.Encode(model.LocalComment)%> 
        <%= Html.Encode(model.IntComment)%>
```

If true display model.LocalComment, if false display model.IntComment.

This doesn't work as I get both values showing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Like C# code in general, you shouldn't write if statements without the curly braces - `{...}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `if` statement always evaluates to true. You are testing whether `model.CountryId` equals `model.CountryId` which is always true: `if (model.CountryId == model.CountryId)`. Also you are missing an `else` statement. It should be like this:

```
<%if (model.CountryId == 1) { %>
    <%= Html.Encode(model.LocalComment) %> 
<% } else if (model.CountryId == 2) { %>
    <%= Html.Encode(model.IntComment) %>
<% } %>
```

Obviously you need to replace `1` and `2` with the proper values.

Personally I would write an HTML helper for this task to avoid the tag soup in the views:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Comment(this HtmlHelper<YourModelType> htmlHelper)
{
    var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
    if (model.CountryId == 1)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(model.LocalComment);
    } 
    else if (model.CountryId == 2)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(model.IntComment);
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

And then in your view simply:

```
<%= Html.Comment() %>
```

Answer (score 6):

Aside from Darin's point about the condition always being true, you might want to consider using the conditional operator:

```
<%= Html.Encode(model.CountryId == 1 ? model.LocalComment : model.IntComment) %>
```

(Adjust for whatever your *real* condition would be, of course.)

Personally I find this easier to read than the big mixture of `<% %>` and `<%= %>`.

Comment: +1 for the often overlooked conditional operator. The null-coalescing operator - `??` - is also quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Conditional Rendering in Asp.Net MVC Views](http://www.iridescence.no/post/Conditional-Rendering-in-AspNet-MVC-Views.aspx)

```
 <% if(customer.Type == CustomerType.Affiliate) %>
   <%= this.Html.Image("~/Content/Images/customer_affiliate_icon.jpg")%>
 <% else if(customer.Type == CustomerType.Preferred) %>
   <%= this.Html.Image("~/Content/Images/customer_preferred_icon.jpg")%>
 <% else %>
   <%= this.Html.Image("~/Content/Images/customer_regular_icon.jpg")%>
```

Comment: That's a hack. A dirty, awful hack that just tries to hide code smell.

Comment: @Dan come on, "hack" is a bit strong here.  Its a gray area--should the controller know handling this situation may be hard for the view?  Should the view's requirements be handled by a new extension method?  I'd call it ugly and harder-to-maintain-than-its-worth but I wouldn't call it an awful hack.

Comment: An extension method that inevitably forces the user to write **more** HTML, and which results in lower readability and maintainability. No, I think 'hack' is a fair assessment!