# Hide Html.TextBoxFor on condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have an ASP.NET MVC2 application. On one of my pages I have a textbox defined in the following manner:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostCode) %>
```

Which is working perfectly.
However, for specific countries (model.Country) I do not want to show this TextBox.

What is the best way of implementing this?

This is an .aspx file, not .cshtml

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18062949/2066026

Comment: Are you using MVC3 or 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using If statement in a MVC Razor View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062882/using-if-statement-in-a-mvc-razor-view)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4573869/2066026

Answer (score 1):

Create a property in your model class, and try this:

```
@if (!Model.IsSpecificCountry) {
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostCode)
}
```

Update:

```
<%if (!Model.IsSpecificCountry) { %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostCode) %> 
<% } %>
```